# how to split text into individual list items

Tags: python

I have a couple sentences of text in the format below:

```
Title: Presenting in a new Forum, Jun-01-2016  # Sentence 1
Source: xyz Website                            # Sentence 2
Type: Special Presentations                    # Sentence 3
From: 14/May/2016                              # Sentence 4
blah blah blah blah                            # Main Paragraph (stretches over 150 words)
```

How can I split them up individually to just get:

```
Title: Presenting in a new Forum, Jun-01-2016
```

and

```
Source: xyz Website
```

and

```
Type: Special Presentations
```

etc

I have tried `el2.split()` but this splits everything into individual words.. I'm trying to get it into a `list` so that I can draw out the `Sentences` individually, as well as the `Main Paragraph` separately.

Comment: [`el2.spliitlines()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_splitlines.htm) should split the string on newlines (`/n`)

Comment: So you want to remove the trailing `#...`?

Comment: Are the sentences in a file, all in one string, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are always going to have title, source, type and from (which are 1 line each) and then a paragraph of arbitrary number of lines:

```
splitted_file = string.splitlines()

title = splitted_file[1]
source = splitted_file[2]
type = splitted_file[3]
_from = splitted_file[4]  # can't use 'from' as a variable name
paragraph = '\n'.join(splitted_file[5:])

print(title)
>> Title: Presenting in a new Forum, Jun-01-2016

print(source)
>> Source: xyz Website

print(type)
>> Type: Special Presentations

print(_from)
>> From: 14/May/2016

print(paragraph)
>> blah blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is from a text file than you can just call .readlines() which returns an array of the lines. If it is a string then split on '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first word of each sentence ends with ':' and the first line of the paragraph doesn't end in ':', the following code should work:

```
string = """\
Title: Presenting in a new Forum, Jun-01-2016  
Source: xyz Website                            
Type: Special Presentations                    
From: 14/May/2016                              
blah blah blah blah                            # Main Paragraph (stretches over 150 words)
"""

paragraph = ''
# when we start the paragraph, there are no more sentences
paragraph_start = False

for line in string.splitlines():
    if line.split()[0].endswith(':') and not paragraph_start:
        print('a Sentence:', line)
    else:
        paragraph_start = True
        paragraph += line + '\n'


print('the paragraph:', paragraph)
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's a string you'll want to use:

```
el2.splitlines()
```

Which will split the string on each new line, and if you need the linebreaks (\n) added to the string you can use:

```
el2.splitlines(5)
```

If el2 is a file you'll want to do it this way:

```
>>> file = open('el2.txt').read()
>>> file
>>> file.split('\n')
```

This will split each line on the linebreak again.

Lastly it sounds like you may be wanting to store them each as separate variables once you have a list (this is not advised when you have large lists) but you could do

```
a = el2.split()
title = a[0]
source = a[1]
```

Here is the PythonFiddle for that http://pythonfiddle.com/split-and-save

Comment: `el2.splitlines(5)` is just an roundabout way of specifying `el2.splitlines(True)` which is unnecessary since it's the default (to keep the newlines).

Comment: @martineau - Thanks for that insight. I read the tutorial point page (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_splitlines.htm) on splitlines and it clearly did a bad job of explaining that. The actual Python docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) provide a better overview of it if anyone is interested.